# export a feature as deployable feature by command line in eclipse for windows

Tags: eclipse, plugins, export

I have an feature project and an plugin project. The feature as you know points that plugin. (I dont know if it is called as "update site" or not)

Anyway, When I rigth click to myfeature project->export->Deploayable Feature->browse the output location-> finish

the exported folder looks like

```
features
   -myFeature.jar
plugins
   -myPlugin.jar
artifacts.jar
content.jar
```

Ok. By using IDE, it works properly. However, I want to do it on command line. I search on the internet, It is realy complicated, while Import command is that much easy:

```
%ECLIPSE_HOME%\eclipsec.exe -nosplash -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -import %My_FEATURE_PROJECT% -data %WORKSPACE_PATH%
```

That command for importing the feature works properly.

I need a kind of command for **exporting** as deployable feature from that myfeatureproject.

Thank you very much from now..

Comment: Any success with that? Will be grateful for help